# AngularJS ui-router $state.go('^') only changing URL in address bar, but not loading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a "Todo App" with angularjs `ui-router`. It has 2 columns:

- Column 1: list of Todos
- Column 2: Todo details or Todo edit form

In the Edit and Create controller after saving the Todo I would like to reload the list to show the appropriate changes. The problem: after calling `$state.go('^')` when the Todo is created or updated, the URL in the browser changes back to `/api/todo`, but the ListCtrl is not executed, i.e. `$scope.search` is not called, hence the Todo list (with the changed items) is not retrieved, nor are the details of the first Todo displayed in Column 2 (instead, it goes blank).

I have even tried `$state.go('^', $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: false });`, no luck.

**How can I do a state transition so the controller eventually gets executed?**

Source:

```
var TodoApp = angular.module('TodoApp', ['ngResource', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/api/todo');

        $stateProvider
            .state('todo', {
                url: '/api/todo',
                controller: 'ListCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/_todo_list.html'
            })
            .state('todo.details', {
                url: '/{id:[0-9]*}',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'DetailsCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_details.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('todo.edit', {
                url: '/edit/:id',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'EditCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('todo.new', {
                url: '/new',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'CreateCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;

    })
;

TodoApp.factory('Todos', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.search = function () {
        Todos.query(function (data) {
            $scope.todos = $scope.todos.concat(data);
            $state.go('todo.details', { id: $scope.todos[0].Id });
        });
    };

    $scope.search();
};

var DetailsCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos) {
    $scope.todo = Todos.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
};

var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.action = 'Edit';

    var id = $stateParams.id;
    $scope.todo = Todos.get({ id: id });

    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos.update({ id: id }, $scope.todo, function () {
            $state.go('^', $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: false });
        });
    };
};

var CreateCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.action = 'Create';

    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos.save($scope.todo, function () {
            $state.go('^');
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: I would say, it is some misunderstanidng about states. check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#nested-states--views. *When the application is in a particular state—when a state is active—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.*, if you go up, you go to existing state. no reload, no refresh... it is the one you've been and you are...

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. Then how can I achieve the required functionality?

Comment: I will tell you my story ;) How I do that: I do call axplicit `$scope.refresh()` created by me and placed on the `parent`, when (or before) I go back from child to parent, E.g. in case of success (After Edit was correct, and have to reload the detail again)... in case of cancel.. I call `$scope.reset()` again declared in parent... but this is just my way ;)

Comment: @Radim Köhler: Sounds good. Can you please modify my code according to these? Just to see how it is put together. (E.g. how to call the `$scope.refresh()` on the parent, etc.

Comment: I am sure, that you've already done it. I am sorry, for later response, but as promised here it is. I'd say that at least the below approach could give you some hints. Please, take it as an inspiration *(code reflects the idea but was written here in SO editor, summarizing my real HOW TO)*. Good luck with angular JS ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Huge thanks for Radim Köhler for pointing out that `$scope` is inherited. With 2 small changes I managed to solve this. See below code, I commented where I added the extra lines. Now it works like a charm.

```
var TodoApp = angular.module('TodoApp', ['ngResource', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/api/todo');

        $stateProvider
            .state('todo', {
                url: '/api/todo',
                controller: 'ListCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/_todo_list.html'
            })
            .state('todo.details', {
                url: '/{id:[0-9]*}',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'DetailsCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_details.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('todo.edit', {
                url: '/edit/:id',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'EditCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('todo.new', {
                url: '/new',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'CreateCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;

    })
;

TodoApp.factory('Todos', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.search = function () {
        Todos.query(function (data) {
            $scope.todos = $scope.todos(data); // No concat, just overwrite
            if (0 < $scope.todos.length) { // Added this as well to avoid overindexing if no Todo is present
                $state.go('todo.details', { id: $scope.todos[0].Id });
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.search();
};

var DetailsCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos) {
    $scope.todo = Todos.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
};

var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.action = 'Edit';

    var id = $stateParams.id;
    $scope.todo = Todos.get({ id: id });

    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos.update({ id: id }, $scope.todo, function () {
            $scope.search(); // Added this line
            //$state.go('^'); // As $scope.search() changes the state, this is not even needed.
        });
    };
};

var CreateCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.action = 'Create';

    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos.save($scope.todo, function () {
            $scope.search(); // Added this line
            //$state.go('^'); // As $scope.search() changes the state, this is not even needed.
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I would give an example *(a draft)* of HOW TO nest `edit` into `detail`. Well, firstly let's amend the templates.

The `Detail` template, contains full definition of the detail. Plus it now contains the attribute `ui-view="editView"`. This will assure, that the **edit**, will "replace" the **detail** from the visibility perspective -  while the **edit** scope will inherit all the **detail** settings. That's the power of *ui-router*

```
<section ui-view="editView">
  <!-- ... here the full description of the detail ... -->
</section>
```

So, secondly let's move the **edit** `state`, into the **detail**

```
// keep detail definition as it is
.state('todo.details', {
    url: '/{id:[0-9]*}',
    views: {
        'detailsColumn': {
            controller: 'DetailsCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/_todo_details.html'
        }
    }
})
// brand new definition of the Edit
.state('todo.details.edit', { // i.e.: url for detail like /todo/details/1/edit
    url: '/edit',
    views: {
        'editView': {    // inject into the parent/detail view
            controller: 'EditCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Having this *adjusted* `state` and `template` mapping, we do have a lot. Now we can profit from the `ui-router` in a full power.

We'll define some methods on a `DetailCtrl` *(remember, to be available on the inherit Edit state)*

```
var DetailsCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos) {

    $scope.id =  $stateParams.id // keep it here

    // model will keep the item (todos) and a copy for rollback
    $scope.model = {
        todos : {},
        original : {},
    }

    // declare the Load() method

    $scope.load = function() {
        Todos
          .get({ id: $stateParams.id })
          .then(function(response){

              // item loaded, and its backup copy created
              $scope.model.todos = response.data;
              $scope.model.original = angular.copy($scope.model.todos);

          });
    };

    // also explicitly load, but just once,
    // not auto-triggered when returning back from Edit-child
    $scope.load()
};
```

OK, it should be clear now, that we do have a `model` with the item `model.todos` and its backup `model.original`.

The Edit controller could have two actions: `Save()` and `Cancel()`

```
var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos) {
    $scope.action = 'Edit';

    // ATTENTION, no declaration of these, 
    // we inherited them from parent view !
    //$scope.id ..     // we DO have them
    //$scope.model ...

    // the save, then force reload, and return to detail
    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos
           .update({ id: id })
           .then(function(response){

              // Success
              $scope.load(); 
              $state.go('^');
           },
           function(reason){

             // Error
             // TODO 
           });
    };

    // a nice and quick how to rollback
    $scope.cancel = function () {
         $scope.model.todos = Angular.copy($scope.model.original);
         $state.go('^');
    };
};
```

That should give some idea, how to navigate between parent/child states and forcing **reload**.

*NOTE in fact, instead of Angular.copy() I am using [lo-dash `_.cloneDeep()`](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) but both should work*

Comment: Thanks for this. But what about the refreshing of the list, if I modify or add a new Todo?

Comment: Won't be the mechanism similar? the list load() or refresh() function published on the upper scope/view *(as `detail` does for `edit`)*... and it could be called as well *(inside of the `save()`)* .. The logic is then the same everywhere... that's the trick ;) I'd say

Comment: What I am trying to say: Instead of managing *reloading* via "state changes" we *should* adjust the thinking about them. The biggest advantage I see there is: 1) The 'todo' state, should show me the list. 2) If I select the item, I won't loose the list, just a child view detail will be **injected** 3) if I click edit, some part of detail view *(if not the whole)* will be extended with edit part. Now, `which model part is updated` based on edit changes... is `in our hands`. While all other pieces, related to these state **do not have to be changed** and that's the way how I do use ui-router ;)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. All I needed was that $scope is inherited and I can call `$scope.load();` before `$state.go('^');`. I have added it and it works. I'll post my solution.

Comment: Awesome! Brilliant. A note: do not forget that inheritance goes via the "View" path. great ;) Enjoy Angular

Answer (score 3):

I might have faced a similar problem the approach i took was to use `$location.path(data.path).search(data.search);` to redirect the page then in the controller I caught the  $locationChangeSuccess event. I other words I use the `$location.path(...).search(...)` as apposed to `$state.go(...)` then caught the $locationChangeSuccess event which will be fired when the location changes occurs before the route is matched and the controller invoked.

```
var TodoApp = angular.module('TodoApp', ['ngResource', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/api/todo');

        $stateProvider
            .state('todo', {
                url: '/api/todo',
                controller: 'ListCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/_todo_list.html'
            })
            .state('todo.details', {
                url: '/{id:[0-9]*}',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'DetailsCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_details.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('todo.edit', {
                url: '/edit/:id',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'EditCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('todo.new', {
                url: '/new',
                views: {
                    'detailsColumn': {
                        controller: 'CreateCtrl',
                        templateUrl: '/_todo_edit.html'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;

    })
;

TodoApp.factory('Todos', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $state, Todos, todo.details) {
    /*here is where i would make the change*/        
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
          $scope.search();
          $route.reload();
    });

        $scope.todos = [];

        $scope.search = function () {
            Todos.query(function (data) {
                $scope.todos = $scope.todos.concat(data);
            });
        };

    $scope.search();
};

var DetailsCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos) {
    $scope.todo = Todos.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
};

var EditCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos, $location) {
    $scope.action = 'Edit';

    var id = $stateParams.id;
    $scope.todo = Todos.get({ id: id });

    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos.update({ id: id }, $scope.todo, function () {
           //here is where I would make a change
                $location.path('todo.details').search($stateParams);
        });
    };
};

var CreateCtrl = function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, Todos, $location) {
    $scope.action = 'Create';

    $scope.save = function () {
        Todos.save($scope.todo, function () {
           //here is where I would make a change
                $location.path('todo.details');
        });
    };
};
```

the $locationChangeSuccess event occurs before the route is matched and the controller invoked

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? I.e. modify my code with this solution. Also at first sight it looks like a 'hack'. What other effects does this have (subscribing to the $locationChangeSuccess)?

Comment: It is a bit of a hack and I would be interested in a better answer myself but I know that it worked for me and my appologies I will change the answer.