# Resolving state every time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I am trying to wrap my head around how the router in 0.2.0 is working.  I have my states set up, I have my state resolving when you go to the url.  What I am having a hard time figuring how best to do is have my data loaded every time that state is transitioned to.

**Router**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('admin.levels',{
        url: '/levels',
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/levels/index.html',
        resolve: {
            levelData: function($q,Levels){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                Levels.query(function(levels) {
                    console.log('resolving state');
                    deferred.resolve(levels);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        },
        controller: 'AdminLevelsController'
    })
    .state('admin.levels.create',{
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/levels/create.html',
        controller: 'AdminLevelsController'
    })
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.levels').controller('AdminLevelsController', ['$scope', '$state','$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Levels','levelData', function ($scope, $state,     $stateParams, $location, Global, Levels, levelData) {

    $scope.new = function(){
        var level = new Levels({
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content
        });

        level.$save(function(response){
            $state.go('admin.levels');
        });
    };
}]);
```

I could be way off, I am fairly new to Angular and just trying to wrap my head around this.  The idea is that you reach the 'index' view and there is a list of levels.  You hit a link to create one, submit the form which calls `new()`, and then that transitions back to the `admin.levels` state.  What I was hoping is that resolve would be called again, but it seems like it only gets called once.  I am guessing this has something to do with the controller already being instantiated and therefore doesn't need to be instantiated again.

I thought that listening for state changes could be an option, but it seemed a little clunky, and I wanted to make sure that was the direction I should go before I head that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was going about this the wrong way.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309366/angularjs-ui-router-state-go-only-changin-url-in-address-bar-but-not-load) finally got me pointed in the right direction.  I knew that the controller wasn't being instantiated again, but I failed to realize that meant the scope was still there and could just be used.  What I ended up doing is just pushing the new level onto my array when it is created:

```
level.$save(function(response){
    $scope.levels.push(response);
    $state.go('^');
});
```

After that, I return to the parent state, where my list resides, and like magic, the new item is there.  In hindsight this makes perfect sense, I just wasn't able to wrap my mind around it.